# Avoiding Wix members confirmation emails or changing the sending address

Tags: wix, velo

I am working with a client who runs a BtoB. We have set up Member Accounts and some member roles to secure sensible information to which they would have access once approved. However, we are running with an issue that is driving me completely crazy: as Wix’s default registration process rules, once someone signs up and we approve Member Access, an email is sent to their account with a token to confirm their email.

Even though we have an email integrated with Wix with our domain, both the confirmation emails and password reset (sent after a user clicks on “forgot my password”), are not being sent from that address, but from some stupid @site-members.com address.

[sender address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmdzE.png)

My client’s clients all use business emails, and most of their servers are completely blocking these emails. Therefore, they are not being able to complete the registration process and never get to login.

After trying to talk to Wix’s support - which was a complete waste of time - I started scouting the internet and found a tutorial for sending Triggered Emails as confirmation emails. I tried it and it seems to work, however, even though the Triggered Email is set to be sent from my account, it adds a via something:

[via ascendbywix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOMf3.png)

Aaaand.. Guess what! After doing some testing, these get blocked as well in many servers.

So, I don’t know what else to do! Can somebody please help me to either avoid sending confirmation emails at all, or to see if there is any other way to set the email address sending those using Corvid or the Wix dashboard?

Just in case you want to see the code, there are three parts to it:

**REGISTRATION LIGHTBOX**

```
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';
import wixData from 'wix-data';
import { doRegistration } from 'backend/register';
let registration;
$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#register").onClick((event) => {
        console.log("Button was clicked");
        $w("#errorMessage").collapse();
        $w("#emailExists").collapse();
        if ($w("#email").valid && $w("#password").valid && $w("#company").valid && $w("#name").valid) { 
            registerPerson();
            console.log("Trying to register");
        } else {
            $w("#errorMessage").expand();
            console.log("Missing Information");
        }
    })
});
function registerPerson () {
 let email = $w("#email").value;
 let password = $w("#password").value;
 let name = $w("#name").value;
 let company = $w("#company").value;
let toInsert = {
 "name": name,
 "company": company,
 "email": email
};
wixData.insert("Members", toInsert)
    .then( (results) => {
 let item = results; 
    } )
    .catch( (err) => {
 let errorMsg = err;
            } );
doRegistration(email, password, name)
        .then((result) => {   
            wixWindow.openLightbox("confirmation");
                let userId = result.user.id
         .catch((err) => {
 let errMsg = err;
            console.log(err);
            $w("#emailExists").expand();
        }       );
        });
}
```

**BACKEND REGISTER.JSW**

```
 
export function doRegistration(email, password, name, company) {
 // register the user
 return wixUsers.register(email, password, {
 "contactInfo": {
 "name": name,
 "company": company
            }
        })
        .then((results) => {
 
            wixUsers.emailUser('verifyRegistration', results.user.id, {
                variables: {
                    approvalToken: results.approvalToken
                }
            });
        return results
        });
}
 
export function doApproval(token) {
 // approve the user
 return wixUsers.approveByToken(token)
 // user is now active, but not logged in
 // return the session token to log in the user client-side
        .then((sessionToken) => {
 return { sessionToken, "approved": true };
        })
        .catch((error) => {
 return { "approved": false, "reason": error };
        });
}
```

**CONFIRMATION PAGE** (where users will be redirected after confirming their email)

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';
import {doApproval} from 'backend/register';
 
$w.onReady( () => {
 // get the token from the URL
 let token = wixLocation.query.token;
 
  doApproval(token)
    .then( (result) => {
 if (result.approved){
 // log the user in
        wixUsers.applySessionToken(result.sessionToken);
          console.log("Approved");
      }
 else {
        console.log("Not approved!");
      }
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

just create the SPF record in the DNS and include everything to it along with the WIX servers (ascendbywix.com ~all).

Comment: Why use the TXT record type instead of the SPF record type?

When SPF records were originally introduced in 2003,   Since that time, the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF)  has discontinued the use of the SPF record and requires that all SPF resource record data be placed into a TXT record type. You may see SPF record types available in your managed DNS provider’s user interface, however, they are NOT the recommended setup for the Sender Policy Framework records.  (RFC 7208 section 3.1)

Add your SPF resource record information into a TXT resource record type.